# Multiple Dapper Execute() statements inside transaction throws NpgsqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable exception

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I'm using dapper with npgsql. (.net core 3.1)

Multiple `connection.Execute(query, params, transaction)` for one connection and inside one transaction throws `This NpgsqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.` exception when calling `commit()` at the end.

No exceptions occurs on each sql execute statement.

When I've debugged code noticed that transaction's `IsCompleted` property set to **true** after first Execute() call.

So I'm not able to run Execute() multiple times inside one transaction?

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString)) {
              connection.Open();
             using (var tr = connection.BeginTransaction()) {
                    foreach (var script in scripts)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            connection.Execute(script.SqlQuery, script.Params);
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            throw; //nothing crashes here
                        }
                    }

                    tr.Commit(); //NpgsqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable
                }
}
```

When the transaction is not used everything works fine, but I need it

---

Upd.

Thanks @Marc Gravell for pointing me to look at the executed sql code.

I've DDL script `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Name (Column type); END;`. The `END;` operator was not necessary here but it led to completion of the transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `connection.Open()` yourself after creating the connection and before creating the transaction:

```cs
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var tr = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
```

Normally Dapper will deal with this internally, but it can't if you have multiple operations that must be on the same underlying connection.

---

Also: tell Dapper about the transaction:

```cs
connection.Execute(script.SqlQuery, script.Params, transaction: tr);
```

Comment: @bidev does the script commit the transaction itself, by any chance? what is the script that is being executed here?

Comment: Thank you  @Marc Gravell for pointing me to look at the executed sql code.

I've DDL script `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Name (Column type); END;`.


The `END;` operator was not necessary here but it led to completion of the transaction.